# why use 0xffff over 65535

Tags: php

I've seen some PHP script which uses **0xffff** in `mt_rand(0, 0xffff)`. I do `echo 0xffff;` and results to **65535**. Is there any significance of using this **0xffff**? And also what is that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The hexadecimal notation `0xffff` makes it clear that all bits in the number are `1`. The `65535` is the same number, but the binary representation isn't as obvious. It's only a count number. So this way of writing numbers has different semantics.

For example, if you want to declare that the maximum value of some variable must be 65535, then it is best to state this like this:

```
$max_value = 65535;
```

Because that makes it easy for humans to compare it to other values like 65500 (`< $max_value`) or 66000 (`> $max_value`).

On the contrary for bit fields.

```
$default_state = 65535;
```

This does not tell me that all the bits are one (when in fact they are).

```
$default_state = 0xFFFF;
```

This does: Each hexadecimal digit stands for four bits, and an `F` means four 1-bits. Therefore `0xFFFF` is `0b1111111111111111` in binary.

Hexadecimal notation is used when the programmer wants to make it clear that the binary representation is of importance, maybe more important than the precise numerical value.

Comment: A lighter explanation please? Pardon my not-so-deep understanding of some technical terms.

Comment: 0xffff = 0b1111111111111111 So it is 16 bits set to 1. Otherwise said 0xffff can be stored on 16 bits and it is the max value that can be stored on 16 bits.

Comment: It's also useful when you want to make it clear that you're using a value that represents the maximum possible value for a particular data type (e.g. `0xFF` for an unsigned byte, `0xFFFF` for an unsigned word, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

If your code is doing binary manipulations, using hex values like this is a lot easier to understand in the context compared with decimal; although I wouldn't consider mt_rand as one of those contexts (especially as the lower bound is decimal and it's only the upper bound that's hex in your example)

Comment: Glad to read this, if that so should be the lower bound decimal (0) be changed to hex then?

Comment: Depends on the context, but it should be consistent.... if you're generating random RGB colour values, then use of hex is consistent

Comment: Well **65535** is the max value of a `signed short int`, seeing **0xffff** (`2^16 - 1`) I know that at once, if I see **65535** I'd asume a normal `signed integer` I guess. It makes it a bit easier to read and understand the code.

Answer (score 6):

It's just the hexadecimal notation for 65535. There is no important difference between the two in the context you provided, but it's easier to remember "0, x and four f characters" than 65535.

Comment: Really? As simple as that. No more other reason?

Comment: Other than Mark's answer, no, not really.

Answer (score 5):

**0xffff** is a hexadecimal number. The **0x** only tells you that the value after the **0x** is hexadecimal. Hexadecimal has **16 digits** from **0 to 9** and from **a to f** (which means, `a = 10, b = 11, c = 12, d = 13, e = 14, f = 15` in a hexadecimal number).

To calculate the decimal value of a hexadecimal number you have to multiply the value of the digits with 16 to the power of the digits place in the number.

Example:

```
ffff = (15*16^3) + (15*16^2) + (15*16^1) + (15*16^0) = 65535
```

In the above case, `f` has a value of 15 and it is in the place 0, 1, 2, and 3 of the number. Then in the following example, hexadecimal 3, 4, and 6 behave with an equivalent decimal value, and `a` has a value of 10.

```
34a6 = (3*16^3) + (4*16^2) + (10*16^1) + (6*16^0) = 13478
```

Hope that could help

Comment: P.S.: a=10  b=11  c=12  d=13  e=14  f=15